FastAPI SSE split responses between two clients
I have a question, but I'm not actually sure it is a real problem, so I hope you can help me.
I'm trying to create notification system using server sent events and FastAPI.
A wrote a simple test server and client, using react.
Now I've started two client app at different browsers and on different ports.
Both of them connects to server and both of them get stream from server, but when I emit some events,
every client get only half of them. So I'm not sure is it because I test it on local machine or it is real problem?
 @socket_router.get('/stream')
 async def message_stream(request: Request, response: Response):

    async def event_generator():
        while True:
            # If client was closed the connection
            if await request.is_disconnected():
                print('disconnected')
                break

            if not len(event_list):
                continue

            # sending_message: BodySchema = event_list.pop()
            for i in range(len(event_list)):
                sending_message = event_list.pop()
                yield {
                    "event": 'message',
                    "id": sending_message.id,
                    "retry": sending_message.retry,
                    "data": sending_message.data
                }
            response.headers['Content-type'] = "text/event-stream"
            response.headers['Cache-Control'] = "no-cache"
            response.headers['Connection'] = 'keep-alive'
            await asyncio.sleep(5)

    return EventSourceResponse(event_generator())

Thanks everyone for your help!
I'm expecting that all tabs will be updated synchronously and get all data on every event.

It seems like you have a global event_list list that you're modifying for each message you're sending: event_list.pop() - every message that gets sent removes it from the list, so it will never be seen by any other source that processes the same list.

Thank you very much. you are absolutely right. Because, It was a test server I used a list in global scope. So if I've understood correctly, First I must iterate all list and then clear it before asyncio.sleep() call
